# Cakephp 2 - Password hash

Tags: cakephp, md5

I had to import huge userdata into a new Application which includes md5-hashed passwords. I told the CakeAUTH to use MD5 and its using it but the hashed password does not match the original hash.

AuthComponent definately uses md5 (debugged through login process using xdebug).

In `SimplePasswordHasher.php` line 52 where it says

```
$this->hash($password)
```

The result is an md5 hash but not matching my original Hash.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In fact,

```
$this->hash($password);
```

is doing

```
Security::hash($string, 'md5', true);
```

(src: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-SimplePasswordHasher.html#41)

So in fact, you are not doing pure `md5($string)` here, you are doing [`md5($salt.$string)`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Security.html#116) where it's a concatenation of salt and string.

If your previous application do not use salt, I think the easiest way is to set your salt to empty. Not recommended, but you can't reverse hashes as well.

To set salt, edit `app/Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Security.salt', '');
```

Not sure if you will get warning though. Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because your app uses a different salt (your other app might have used none at all), check `Security.salt` in your [`Config/core.php`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration).

So to fix that you will have to use either the same, or no salt at all, though none of this is a good idea if you ask me.

I'd suggest that you force the users to create new passwords, and use a safer password hashing algorithm like bcrypt. See

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::hash
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords

Just for the record, [a custom password hasher](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes) would probably be the best way to work with foreign hashes:

```
App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class BackCompatPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {

    public function hash($password) {
        return md5($password);

        // or using a custom salt if necessary
        // return md5('the-other-apps-salt' . $password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
        return $hashedPassword === $this->hash($password);
    }

}
```

Comment: @gonzela2006 In `app/Controller/Component/Auth/BackCompatPasswordHasher.php`, please check the linked documentation.